# devtunnels.ms tunnel port forwarding giving response 413 Request Entity Too Large if I upload large file

Tags: port, vscode-extensions, portforwarding, tunnel, http-tunneling

I tried local port forwarding to the internet in vscode, it runs smoothly. However my web app is about uploading video/image. So when I upload video with size `63 MB` I got error after checked it in network inspect element with XHR as client:

My forwarded address running on `https://npzg*****-****.asse.devtunnels.ms/`

```
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But it runs perfectly if I upload video with size 1MB.

How do I setup maximum upload size for tunnel server?

I tried reading this [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), but it didn't helpful.

Edit:
Here is most
[related docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/cli-commands) but still didn't helpful for 413 entity too large, I cannot find how to handle that request in `devtunnel` command.

I see why, it said that max request body is 16MB based on this [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#dev-tunnels-limits)

Comment: The documentation you posted is about developing remotely with vscode, you need to look up how to configure your web app or server to handle larger file uploads. They're totally separate issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to configure my web app, it runs perfectly in localhost when I upload large file. Also I didn't use nginx, that nginx come from tunnel server from devtunnels.ms I'm not sure if I have control to setup that nginx from tunnel provider which is microsoft. In my code, there's no response that return 413.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Using localhost everything works, but with devtunnel I get the very similar error message. if some knowledgeable person can shed some light, that'd be REALLY helpful. thanks a bunch!